# (C++) Need help with database

Tags: c++, database, string, inheritance, char

I'm trying to make a database and so far, I've been using strings to store my entries from a text file into an array, but this just isn't working out. Thus, I began thinking of a new way of doing it.

What I want to do:

Lets say I have a text file with the following database...

John Smith   00001 jsmith@email  pw1
Rob  Deniro  00002 rdeniro@email pw2
Al   Pacino  00003 apacino@email pw3

Joe  Pesci   00004  jpesci@email  307  pw4
Joaq Phoenix 00005  jphoe@email   208  pw5
John Madden  00006  jmadden@email 708  pw6

Alright, so basically what I'm stuck at is making this "inheritance" friendly. What's the best way to go about storing each entry?  Individual strings?  I've been thinking that the best way is to store each individual character until a whitespace occurs and then storing it into a string, but I'm not sure how that could be done.

Comment: What do you mean with inheritance, there is no connection between inheritance and reading strings, at least no obvious relation I can think of

Answer (score 3):

As TomWij says, you do ifstream then strtok, but I'd recommend you escape your strings with "", not just spaces, that way you can store "something like this, for example a note about the user", that's how its done with CSV (comma separated values).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void readCSV(std::istream &input, std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > &output)
{
    std::string csvLine;
    // read every line from the stream
    while( std::getline(input, csvLine) )
    {
        std::istringstream csvStream(csvLine);
        std::vector<std::string> csvColumn;
        std::string csvElement;
        // read every element from the line that is seperated by commas
        // and put it into the vector or strings
        while( std::getline(csvStream, csvElement, ',') )
        {
            csvColumn.push_back(csvElement);
        }       
        output.push_back(csvColumn);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::fstream file("file.csv", ios::in);
    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File not found!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // typedef to save typing for the following object
    typedef std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > csvVector;
    csvVector csvData;

    readCSV(file, csvData);
    // print out read data to prove reading worked
    for(csvVector::iterator i = csvData.begin(); i != csvData.end(); ++i)
    {
        for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << *j << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which brings me to the real solution, why don't you use a CSV library like  [CSV module](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/libmba/dl/src/csv.c)  or better yet, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), SQLite is dead easy to install and use, and its all around better than coding a database by hand, besides it shouldn't take you more than 1 hour to get [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) into your codebase, since its API is REALLY easy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
    printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  sqlite3 *db;
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  int rc;

  if( argc!=3 ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s DATABASE SQL-STATEMENT\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
  if( rc ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(1);
  }
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, argv[2], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }
  sqlite3_close(db);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmz, sad to see that sqlite3 doesn't throw exceptions to handle errors.

Comment: Well SQLite is C compatible, so it can't throw errors, they don't exist in C, so you'd have to resort to longjmp, or errno (not thread safe) which aren't features many people like to use, thus errors must be handled like this. You should probably wrap it in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the term "database" is reserved to the standard notion of a relational database such as MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle etc'

So this begs the question why don't you use a standard relational database?

you might want to try looking up [TinySQL](http://www.jepstone.net/tinySQL/)

Comment: Exactly!  Stop reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Read one line at a time with [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) and then use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok.html) to split each line, use the whitespace as the delimiter. You should use `string` except for the numeric values, which you can save as an `int` or a `long` if you need to support big values. It's also more wise to store the passwords in an encrypted way if you want security.

You might want to look for another solution to store your data instead of plain text for various reasons: Space, performance, security, ... It might be a good idea to try to use binary database files.

Comment: I'm aware of ifstream, but when you say "read one line at a time" do you mean to use getline()?

Also, I'm making a database, so passwords could be changed to anything, so int wouldn't work for them.  Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes, I mean using the module ifstream, and for reading a line getline() is indeed the method you want to call. I didn't state to save passwords as an int, only numeric values should be saved as ints. Besides that, another way of storing a password doesn't prevent it from being changed.

Comment: Please note that I have added another paragraph to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, misread you there.  Anyway, would this work well with inheritance?

Comment: using white space for the delimiter would not work easily since the name can have multiple words as it is presented.

Comment: It would only work if he decides to store the first name and last name apart, but indeed, another delimiter would be better. Reading data doesn't have much to do with inheritance, why would it affect that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<fstream>
 using namespace std;




int main(int argc, char *argv[])



  {

     char Name[100];

     char FTE[100];
      cout<<"What is the file name?\n";
      cin>>FTE;

   ifstream myfile (FTE);     

   while(1)
    {


    myfile.getline(Name, 30, '|');
    cout<<line;
   cin.ignore();


 }
  }
```

all this does is read all your text entries seperated by the '|' Character. Good for making Flat File Databases in C++ and other using same methods.